# Find the function which satisfies the following functional equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is the equation

$$e^{ia}f\left[\int_{0}^a e^{ix}f(x)dx\right]=\int_{0}^a e^{ix}f(x)dx$$

I tried but wasn't able to figure out.

Any suggestion towards how should I approach it are appreciated.

**My attempt :**

I tried to differentiate with respect to $a$.

I got this :

$$f(a) = e^{ia}f’\left(\int_{0}^a e^{ix}f(x)dx\right)f(a) + if\left[\int_{0}^a e^{ix}f(x)dx\right]$$

then I tried to equate real and imaginary part but nothing happened.

Comment: Is $a$ a fixed constant, or does it represent a variable in $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: No a is arbitrary variable

Comment: Assume for the moment $f$ is differentiable; try taking the derivative of both sides, see what you get

Comment: Show what you tried anyway - that is important to this forum

Comment: it was a mistake this is the real problem

Comment: How about setting $g(a)=\int_0^a e^{ix}f(x)dx$ and think of this as a (differential) equation for $g$?

Comment: Note: whatever $f$ is, it must be that $f(0)=0.$